# oData - applying filters to SQL queries

Tags: odata

I am relatively new to oData service and I am trying to explore if oData is feasible for my project.

From all the examples / demos that I have come across,every demo always loads up all data into the repository and then oData filters are applied over the data.

Is there a way to not load up all data (apply the filters to SQL from oData) from SQL which will obviously be highly inefficient for N number of requests coming in /second ?

So for example if I had a movies service :

localhost:4502/OdataService/movies(55)

The above example is actually just filtering for movie id 55 from an "entire" set of movies.Is there a way to make this filter happen at SQL level instead of bloating the memory first with all movies and then allowing oData to filter it?

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you definately sure this is the case? As long as you have not enumerated your IQueryable before you return it from your controller action the OData query should execute against the db just fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Odata to get huge amount of data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974634/using-odata-to-get-huge-amount-of-data)

Comment: I'm trying with a Table Valued Function, but in that case, EF reads everything returned by the function, and seem to apply the OData filters later. Is there a way to avoid that when using a TVF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out after doing a small POC that Entity framework takes care of building dynamic query based on the request.

Comment: What if you are using `ADO.Net` and not `Entity Framework` on your project. Are there any options to apply filtering at the database side?

Comment: If we have 100 properties in the data / 100 rows in the table, then how to know which filter user will pass($filter= x/y/z eq 'a/b/v' , based on the same how to prepare a Query in EF?