# How to limit the amount of data from an OData request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5, odata

I have a Users table of 76 users and UserGroups table.

Using MVC, OData, a generic repository and EF, I am trying to optimize data retrieval when filtering based on the user group:

```
/api/Users?$filter=USERGROUPS/any(usergroup: usergroup/ID eq 'Group1')
```

On the client side, I get the right number of users - 71 (as OData is filtering based on the result), however I want to limit the number of records being returned form the actual query - ie. I do not want to return all records then filter (not optimal for very large data sets).

My API controller method is as follows:

```
    [Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    public IQueryable<USER> Get()
    {
        var unitOfWork = new ATMS.Repository.UnitOfWork(_dbContext);

        var users = unitOfWork.Repository<USER>()
                              .Query()
                              .Include(u => u.USERGROUPS)
                              .Get()
                              .OrderBy(order => order.USERNAME);

        unitOfWork.Save();      // includes Dispose()

        return users.AsQueryable();
    }
```

I read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974634/using-odata-to-get-huge-amount-of-data) that:

> Entity framework takes care of building dynamic query based on the
>   request.

However, using a SQL Server profiler, the query executed is requesting all the records, rather than a filtered query.

Adding a .Take() to the query does not accomplish the desired result, as we also need the actual number of records returned for paging purposes.

I was thinking of using the grabbing some properties through ODataQueryOptions, but that doesn't seem quite right either.

Is my implementation of Unit of Work and Repository incorrect, in relation to what I am trying to accomplish, and if so, how can this be corrected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple - Just set the Page size for the Queryable atrribute [Queryable(PageSize=10)]

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options#server-paging

If You'd tell the EF where to apply the options, it would work. 
Like this :

```
    //[Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    public IQueryable<USER> Get(ODataQueryOptions<USER> options)
    {

        var users = options.ApplyTo(_dbContext.Set<USER>()
                              .Query()
                              .Include(u => u.USERGROUPS)
                              .Get()
                              .OrderBy(order => order.USERNAME));

        return users;
    }
```

Your code didn't work, because it tried to apply the options onto the last line "users.AsQueryable()", so what actually happened, is that EF pull the FULL dataset, and then applied the query onto the last line (that being a in memory collection). And that's why You didn't see that "filter" not being passed to the SQL.

The mechanics are such, that EF tries to apply the Query, to the IQueryable collection that it finds in the code (there's still a question how does it find the correct line).

Comment: I see how that's working and the url provided for the next set of data, however, when looking at SQL Profiler, all the request is for all of the data.  Maybe if someone can explain the mechanics of this, and how not all the data is returned then filtered?

Comment: Ok, however with the code you posted, there is a problem with the code inside the options.ApplyTo() brackets:  Argument type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<ATMS.DAL.USER>' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Linq.IQueryable'.  Adding .AsQueryable); at the end of the OrderBy fixes it, but still the return type is incorrect.

Comment: Also in addition to this, lets say we only get 10 records back from the db, is there a subsequent call or part of the call made to retrieve the total number of records?

Comment: Well, that kinda answers - Your problem is the answer to Your solution :) You can only apply filter to a Iqueryable collections. That's kinda the main idea and the main difference between IEnumerable and Iqueryable.

Comment: If you could use smth from DBContext that returns IQueryable - You'd be OK. If You use Ienumerable, as a source, all that can be done is filter the dataSet in Memory.

Comment: The options.ApplyTo() gets applied at the server, and results are returned from EF, HOWEVER -NO- results are returned to the client.   See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130813/why-are-there-missing-client-side-results-when-using-odata-options-with-entity-f

Comment: Looking at this further an having implementing a working solution (http://www.whatsinyourlunch.com/odata-kendo-ui-entity-framework-webapi/) you cannot mix the Queryable attribute and options.ApplyTo. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130813/why-are-there-missing-client-side-results-when-using-odata-options-with-entity-f/18134274?noredirect=1#18134274